# Why the Rx.NET Finally block is not called?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Please, observe the following simple Rx.NET program:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace observables
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var src = Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
                .Take(1)
                .Do(o => Debug.WriteLine(o))
                .Finally(() => Debug.WriteLine("************ Finally"));
            src.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

It displays:

```
0
************ Finally
```

Now, when I remove the `Do` block from the monad, the program does not display anything!

Why?

Comment: Are you also removing the `Take` or just the `Do`?

Comment: The code ran fine when I tested it on LINQPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a race condition between the Observable thread and the Main thread.

The function call `src.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` does not wait for the Observables `Finally` since it's run on different thread.

Try running it multiple times: you will see that the `Debug.WriteLine` succeeds occasionally, at least on my Visual Studio setup.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I thought `GetResult()` should block until the entire observable is exhausted, now you are saying that `Finally` is called afterwards. I was unaware of it.

Comment: @mark - He's saying that there is a race condition whereby `.Finally(...)` is called on a different thread, at the point when the observable ends (but not afterwards), so that `GetResult()` can finish before the `.Finally(...)` code has a chance to complete.